# How to calculate with $y(t+Δt)$ definition of derivative to the other side using $Δt limes(=approaches) 0$?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, differential-geometry

$Δ t$ is small time, so $y(t)$ stays constant this time. Presume that you know value $y(t)$ and calculate using it the following $y(t+Δ t)$. Arrange the terms so that when you calculate the limit when $Δt \times 0$, you get definition of derivative to the other side?

i think i should get something like $Δy/Δt$, but if i calculate $(y(t+Δt)-y(t))/((t+Δt)-t)$.

I dont get it..help me thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to know a formula for $y=f(t)$ to make such a calculation. For example if $f(t)=t^2$ then $f(t+h)-f(t)=(t+h)^2-t^2=2th+h^2.$ Then in this case $(t+h)-t=h,$ so after simplifying you get $2t+h,$ and now as $h \to 0$ the derivtive appears as $ 2t$.

On the other hand if $f(t)=c,$ a constant, the calculation will simplify to $0,$ with no $h$ remaining, so the derivative will be $0.$

Note that above I used $h$ fo $\Delta t.$ I don't follow your meaning when you say that just because $h$ is small, $f(t)$ will stay constant.

Comment: Ok, so my bigger question is the following. I have a tank filled with air 500l and new polluted air is coming in with 30l/min with concentration of 1liter of chemical(=0,88mol). And from tank is  being sucked out 30l/min air with concentration of y(t). Now I have to make DY, which I guess would be dy/dt=30l/min*(0,88/30l/min)-30l/min*y(t). But to this point I have to use the limit according to the change of time when it is approaching 0, and this would give me definition of derivative to the other side. I also know that in the beginning y(t)=0 and t=0.